# what differences between tf.FixedLenFeature, tf.VarLenFeature and tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature in tensorflow 1.10

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have read the TensorFlow doc before then I find `tf.FixedLenFeature` is used for `fixed-length` data and both `tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature` and `tf.VarLenFeature` can be used for `variable-length` data.
And the TensorFlow API doc is not described detailed enough so I am wondering the difference between these in TensorFlow 1.10.

Comment: In the latest Tensorflow version(2.8.0), `tf.FixedLenFeature` and `tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature` are moved to tf.io API. You can find more details about `tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/FixedLenSequenceFeature) and `tf.io.FixedLenFeature` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/FixedLenFeature). In both the reference links usage examples are given. You get more clarity by going through provided examples.